# An optimal solution to check if statement

Tags: python, performance, optimization, conditional-statements, software-design

I am developing an app, and I have a simple question to ask. In my database I am using, I have to store the values based on a conditional statement. For example I have 4 variables (x1,y1) and (x2,y2).

```
If x1 != 0:
    y1 = 0
    x2 = 0
    y2 = x1

If y1 != 0:
    X1 = 0
    Y2 = 0
    X2 = y1

If x2 != 0:
    X1 = 0
    Y2 = 0
    Y1 = x2

If y2 != 0:
    X1 = y2
    Y2 = 0
    X2 = 0
```

So on and so forth. If we follow this logic we will end up with 4 conditionals statements.

I want to know whether there is a simple way for doing that instead of writing all these conditions in my code.

Comment: That's not valid Python.

Comment: And it looks fishy that you assign to different variables (e.g., `y2` vs `Y2`).

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the conditions we can see that if `x1` or `y2` is set, then `y1` and `x2` will not be, and vice versa. So we can divide these into two conditions, one in which there is `x1` or `y2` set, and another in which `y1` or `x2` is set. We can then zero the other values whenever we enter the respective relevant condition. There is one edge case where `x1` and `x2` are zero, `y1` and `y2` are not zero, and for that, we need to only enter the first conditional if `x1` is set or `y2` is set and `y1` is not set.

Then we have to deal with the respective values themselves. We can see that `y2` is equivalent to `x1` if `x1` is set, and `x1` is equivalent to `y2` if `y2` is set and `x1` was not set. So, we simply give preference to `x1` if it is set first, otherwise, we default to `y2` for both values and vice versa for the other condition. The condensed conditionals would look as such:

```py
if x1 or y2 and not y1:
    y1 = x2 = 0
    x1 = y2 = x1 or y2
if x2 or y1:
    x1 = y2 = 0
    x2 = y1 = x2 or y1
```

Comment: I see, that was an edge case I missed, in that case, I'll expand the first conditional to only enter on `y2` if `y1` is not set.

Comment: Might now match what the OP was trying to write. I wish they'd fix/respond, then I could simply test instead of trying to untangle their spaghetti in my head :-)